# CISC and RISC - synchronous and asynchronous

Tags: asynchronous, synchronization, embedded, processor, risc

I have two opposing ideas. I think that all the instructions in a RISC take the same time what makes me believe RISC is associated with synchronous.

At the same time i think that CISC should be synchronous and RISC should be asynchronous.

Can you tell me if RISC is associated with asynchronous and CISC is associated with synchronous? WHY???

Thanks!

Comment: That's pretty much the same question as "Why use RISC CPUs green powerpoints, and CISC blue?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by synchronous and asynchronous.  If you are talking about logic clocking, then cisc vs risc vs a hard disk controller dont matter, it is just some logic that you are clocking.   And when it comes to processors if you are thinking in whether they can perform operations in series or parallel, it also doesnt matter between the two because both can be implemented either way.  Some CISC processors are a shell around a risc or vliw or some flavor of other processor.  If you are thinking parallel execution vs serial, in order or out of order execution, again the two dont matter with either one if you have the right logic and the right pipelines you can look ahead and execute out of order and in parallel.

It is like saying there are red sweaters and green sweaters made from red and green yarn.  they are still just a combination of knit and purl stitches.  Logic is just a lot of primitive gates, be it a disk controller chip, sound card chip, or processor, you can implement the logic in as many ways as you can implement a program to solve a particular problem.  Machine code is nothing more than a bunch of bits fed into a bunch of gates, there is nothing special about how risc works vs cisc other than the number of bits you feed and the number of gates to implement.  One might be easier to implement than another but it is still just some number of logic gates.

Comment: I am taking a first aprouch to computer science in a subject about embedded systems, so i don't know some concepts. In a teacher question he asks to stablish the nexus between CISC/RISC and clock synchronicity/asynchronicity of data transfer. What should i have answered?

Comment: still an unclear question.  off chip/processor data transfer has nothing to do with cisc vs risc.  you need the teacher to elaborate.  still dont know what you mean by sync/async in this context.  must have been some vague reference or notion in the textbook or during a lecture, or the teacher doesnt know what they are talking about, or is thinking at a really high level rather than down in reality.  need more info. did the teacher follow up after asking that?  does the teacher have office hours?

Comment: He was talking about synchronous(it's the clock that orders when to operate) and asynchronous(needs ACK) microprocessors and to introduce CISC and RISC he made a introduction and asked the question. He answered RISC is associated with asynchronous and CISC is associated with synchronous. But i didn't understood why

Comment: still doesnt make any sense, there is some detail missing to close the gap on what he was trying to say.  either he didnt say it or say it right or you didnt absorb it right.  if you are concerned about it you should go back and ask during office hours or in the class..  dont say some guy on the internet doesnt know what you are talking about, just take your own confusion in there, your own words, and get the teacher to close the gap.  If he is a good teacher he will be able to do that, if a bad teacher then maybe he didnt explain what he was trying to say in the first place...

Comment: or ask some of the other students in the class if they understood.